# Measure the time to reach the main function using perf?

Tags: linux, benchmarking, perf

I would like to measure my program initialization time by measuring the time to reach the main function, so that I get the time of "run-time initializations" (eg. bss sections set to 0 and global constructors called).

How could I use `perf` to do so?

Comment: off-topic: BSS zeroing is "lazy", done with virtual memory trickery.  On read, the page-fault handler copy-on-write maps it to the shared physical page of zeros.  On write, a new anonymous page is allocated and zeroed to back it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to consider that `perf` doesn't really measure time - it records events. Now you can do some profiling and look at call stacks and derive some information about initialization, but in order to measure a specific time, we need to record the beginning and end timestamp.

In case of the *time to reach the `main` function*, we can use

1) A dynamic tracepoint on `main`:

```
$ sudo perf probe -x ./gctor main Added new event:   probe_gctor:main  (on main in ./gctor)
```

You can now use it in all perf tools, such as:

```
perf record -e probe_gctor:main -aR sleep
```

This does require pretty high privileges, I'll just use root in the example.

2) A sensible point for the "start" of your binary.

I suggest the tracepoint `syscalls:sys_exit_execve`. This is basically right after `perf record` started to execute your binary. This works in my version (5.3.7) - if it doesn't for you, you may need to tinker around. You could of course just use `-e cycles`, but then you get spammed later on with events you don't want.

Putting it together:

```
sudo perf record -e probe_gctor:main -e syscalls:sys_exit_execve ./gctor
                  ^ this is what perf probe told you earlier
```

And then look at it with `perf script --header`

```
# time of first sample : 77582.919313
# time of last sample : 77585.150377
# sample duration :   2231.064 ms
[....]
# ========
#
           gctor 238828 [007] 77582.919313: syscalls:sys_exit_execve: 0x0
           gctor 238828 [001] 77585.150377:         probe_gctor:main: (5600ea33414d)
```

You can either compute it from these two samples, or use the `sample duration` if there are really only the two samples in your trace.

For completeness: Here's a way to do it with `gdb`:

```
gdb ./gctor -ex 'b main' -ex 'python import time' -ex 'python ts=time.time()' -ex 'run' -ex 'python print(time.time()-ts)'
```

This is much less accurate, has about 100 ms overhead on my system, but it doesn't require higher privileges. You could of course improve on this by just building your own runner with `fork/ptrace/exec` in C.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. I knew the gdb technique but it has indeed too much overhead. So, fyi, it gives me similar results to having the `main` function directly returning and measuring its overall execution time with `perf stat`.

Comment: btw, it seems to have a bit more (acceptable) overhead than the dummy `perf stat` technique - probably coming from the interrupts involved in the tracepoints?

Comment: I would not expect more than a few microseconds of overhead from the tracepoint.

Comment: @JulioGuerra: Are you sure you're controlling for CPU frequency variation?

Comment: Last note on the solution: I actually put a probe in the binary entry address rather than `sys_exit_execve`.
@PeterCordes I only set the frequency governor to `performance`.

Comment: @JulioGuerra: But you didn't do any warm-up before starting the process?  The CPU doesn't jump to max turbo *instantly* even with governor = `performance` and/or energy_power_preference set to performance.

Comment: I do with `perf stat` using the `-r` option to give a high number of runs. We don't have this option in `perf record` and will have to do something similar if I go further with it indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Put something that terminates the process immediately with little or no cleanup, like [exit_group](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit_group.2.html), as the first thing in main and then use `perf stat` (looking at task-clock) or simply `time` to measure the process runtime.

If you don't need to use `perf` specifically, a non-destructive way is to use the `clock()` call, which measures CPU time since process start and for most processes (which don't launch threads or block before main) is ~equal to real time spent before main if you issue it at the start of main.

I often use `clock()` along with perf's --delay option to *exclude* start-up costs from a measurement. That actually leads to a third approach - take the difference in stats between a run with and without a --delay argument that excludes startup. This is useful if you want to get perf stats other than time for the startup portion.

Comment: [`abort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html) isn't the fastest way to exit.  Maybe an inline asm `asm("mov $231, %eax; syscall");` 
(x86-64 exit_group) would be a better bet than calling a library function that raises SIGABRT.  (Lazy dynamic linking, and 2 system calls to unblock and then raise a signal)

Comment: @Peter good point, I changed it to exit_group (if abort writes a core dump it might be a really bad choice although it isn't totally clear to me if that would be captured in task-clock or time). I didn't suggest inline asm though but it's here in the comment if they'd like the save off the last few microseconds.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to provide your own executable entry point that records the timestamp counter and then transfers control to the standard entry point `_start`. When `main` is entered you can subtract that from now to get the exact cycle count of C or C++ run-time start-up.

Working example:

```
[max@supernova:~/src/test] $ cat test.cc
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern uint64_t start_tsc;

int main() {
    uint64_t main_tsc = __builtin_ia32_rdtsc();
    printf("C/C++ run-time start took %lu cycles.\n", main_tsc - start_tsc);
}

[max@supernova:~/src/test] $ cat mystart.asm
        global mystart
        global start_tsc
        extern _start

        section .text
mystart:
        push rdx
        rdtsc
        shl rdx, 32
        or rax, rdx
        mov [rel start_tsc], rax
        pop rdx
        jmp _start

        section .data
start_tsc:
        dq 0

[max@supernova:~/src/test] $ make
g++ -o test.o -c -W{all,extra,error} -g -Og test.cc
nasm -felf64 -o mystart.o mystart.asm
g++ -o test -g -Wl,-emystart test.o mystart.o 

[max@supernova:~/src/test] $ ./test
C/C++ run-time start took 5314 cycles.
```

Comment: You should be able to use `jmp _start` even in a PIE executable; CRT `_start` gets statically linked into the executable so it's going to be within +-2GiB of `my_start` and a rel32 jump can reach; you don't need a 64-bit absolute address.

Comment: Also for the data, use `[rel start_tsc]` like a normal person (or use `default rel`).  Also, don't call NASM source files `.S`; that's for GAS syntax sources.  Call them `.asm`.  You don't need to save/restore `rdx` either; the normal CRT code doesn't depend on it being zeroed on process entry.  It might also be smaller to just store the two halves of the TSC separately, although shr/or to create a qword in a register is fairly idiomatic.

Comment: @PeterCordes I take your points, thanks. With regards to `rdx`, I looked into [glibc `start.S`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/start.S;h=ae08f98180e45f39402459747e462da8d94bb64d;hb=HEAD) and `rdx` seems to be used, so that is why I preserve it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Interesting point about using two stores for saving TSC. One store may be better, since the CPU can only issue 1-2 stores per cycle, so it makes sense to minimize the number stores (since we took the trouble of writing assembly we might as well split hair).

Comment: Ah right, I'd forgotten which register the ABI specifies for that.  And I was thinking of this as the real process entry point (so RDX would just be zero), but that's only true in a static executable where the dynamic linker doesn't run first.  Thanks for that link.

Comment: Re: efficiency.  It's true that the rest of the startup code may do a lot of storing so it's barely plausible that we'd bottleneck on 1 store per clock.  But that's highly unlikely.  The things we should be optimizing for are total uop count for the issue/rename bottleneck, and code-size and decoder considerations. This isn't a loop; out-of-order exec will overlap those 2 back-to-back stores with lots of later instructions. The store buffer and ROB are plenty large enough to absorb two back-to-back stores, especially since they're to the same cache line. 2 mov stores = 2 uops, vs. your 3

Comment: Oh, and if you want speed instead of code-size, save RDX in RCX or any other register instead of the stack.  But `push`/`pop` are small.  I think for maximum clarity / human reader benefit you should probably just leave it as-is.  This is one of the few times saving a byte or cycle is trumped by human reader considerations, IMO, since this code only runs once per process and is only useful for manual experimentation.

Comment: @PeterCordes You beat me by a second, I was about to say that instead of push/pop it could scratch another register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, push/pop makes it clear that the register is being preserved. I like how each line of assembly can have its own little code review.